# How to represent companies as vectors and find the similarities between them?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I'm trying to represent a company as a feature vector. The vector has multiple stats describing the company such as earnings growth, capital expenditures, gross margin, etc.

The goal is to represent companies with these vectors and find the most similar companies based on some similarity measure (ie euclidean or cosine).

My questions are: Would this be an accurate way to represent companies? Is there some normalization I have to do to the vectors before finding similarity? And what is the best measure of similarity for these vectors?

Comment: My goal is to find the similarity between the features that each company has, so by 'represent' I mean a way to store these features for comparison against the stored features of other companies. I'm aware this is primitive, it is more of a test run before adding more complexity.

Comment: The problem here is that you are comparing apples to oranges. You have a bunch of different measurements that have some corrolation to each other but to make direct comparisons to each other requires some subjective choices. How important is a given rate of earnings growth as compared to a given amount of capital expenditure, for example? This is going to differ from investor to investor. And probably with time as well. A company that has just made some heavy capital expenditures is likely not to need as much for awhile, while a company with light past expenditures may need to increase.

Comment: When you do your comparisons between vectors, you are actually doing these direct comparisons between disparate measures. By changing your choices of unit-of-measurement for various dimensions, you change the relationships between the vectors.  Some which were close together may be come far apart, while others that were far apart may become close. Unless you have a solid basis for how to compare earnings growth vs capital expenditures, for example, any comparisons between vectors are pointless.